# how to reflect UDP packet on port 53 in java?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I wrote this program in Java and I am running it under Ubuntu 14.

When running it, it sends UDP packets over port 53 to a caching DNS server which runs under Debian 8.0.

The server sends replies to the source. How can I modify the program to make the server reply to another IP address instead in the same LAN ?

Here is the program:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;


public class ClientSender {
private static Object InetAdress;


public static void main(String[] args) {

int i ;

for (i=0;i<1000;i++){

DatagramSocket skt;

try{
           /////////////////////////////////////////
    skt = new DatagramSocket();     /////creating socket
    String msg = "Test";//////////message

    byte[] b =msg.getBytes(); /// creating message

            InetAddress host =InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.3"); ///destination IP address

            int serverSocket = 53; // Destination Port

               ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            DatagramPacket request =new DatagramPacket(b,b.length,host,serverSocket);
            skt.send(request);                                                        /////////////////////////creating packet

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //..................................// for receiving replies from destnation
            byte [] buffer = new byte[1000];
            DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket (buffer, buffer.length);
            skt.receive(reply);                ///////////////////////////////////lestining to replies from destination

            skt.close();///////////////closing socket

            System.out.println(new String(request.getData()));
            System.out.println(new String(reply.getData()));



}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        }
}}

}
```

Comment: You can't; the IP/port pair used for a socket is linked to this socket. And why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Thank you for every thing...I am working on a project for protecting DNS server from DNS Reflection based attack, but I cannot perform the reflection part. I am used java in some mini projects, but I am new in java socket programming, and I hoped I could do that, is there any other method to do that reflection on a small scale?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in Java.

Your current client IP-Address would forbid the server to choose a different client's IP-Address in your lan-connection.

It is not possible in Java.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
But how can I do that?. How can I make the DNS server reflect the sent packet into another IP address?